# Python: check if it socket or file

Tags: python, sockets

I want to get data from stdin and pass it over to a server. And vice versa: get data from the server and display in the terminal. Of course I don't want to block neither the stdin nor the socket. Here is a piece of code:

```
while True:
    inputready = select.select([server_socket, sys.stdin], [], [], self.timeout)[0]
    for src in inputready:
        ...
```

Is it possible to figure the type of *src* here?

Are there any other ways, you can think of, to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are there any other ways, you can think of, to solve the problem?

You could just check:

```
for src in inputready:
    if src == server_socket:
        ...
```

---

Now back to your first question, you could:

- Use [`os.fstat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) to get a stat buffer
- Use [`stat.S_ISSOCK`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#module-stat) to check if it's a socket

Again, there's little reason to do this.